# CSS styles for pipedrive web form (embeded as iframe)

Tags: iframe

i want to add css styles for embedded form from pipedrive (it embeded as iFrame).

I cant add styles by javascript, because i get security error: `Blocked a frame with origin "https://my-site.com/" from accessing a cross-origin frame.`

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow!  Would you mind editing your post and showing us specifically what you've attempted?